# Why can one still buy newspapers during lockdown?

Tags: media, covid-19, policy

In the middle of the Covid-19 lockdown, at least in [France](https://www.gouvernement.fr/info-coronavirus) and in [Italy](http://www.governo.it/it/articolo/decreto-iorestoacasa-domande-frequenti-sulle-misure-adottate-dal-governo/14278) newsagents are in the list of first-necessity stores that remain open. "To go buy a newspaper" is a legitimate reason to leave one's house.

I wonder about the motivations of this decision: buying a newspaper is not essential by any definition of the term. Television, radio and internet are largely sufficient to cover the need for information of the general population.

Is there a reasonable political explanation for this? At first sight, it seems that the only one is the ties and the balance of power between politicians and news outlets / medias.

Comment: Because some old people don't have Internet and that's the only way they can keep themselves informed of what's happening.

Comment: There are also people who choose not to have TV - I'm one, though I obviously do have internet :-)

Comment: @dan-klasson and jamesqf This is already addressed in my question: *Television, radio and internet are largely sufficient to cover the need for information*. I find it difficult to believe that there is a statistically significant number of people that have no access to internet, radio *or* television.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Denying an old person access to a newspaper is like taking away social media from a teenager. But yeah, I get your point. Kinda silly rule.

Comment: Well, there are toilet paper shortages.

Comment: @Federico Poloni: Your personal difficulty of belief is not necessarily an accurate reflection of reality, you know.

Comment: Because they want to scare to death as many people as possible.

Comment: @Acccumulation  That's the Sun, though, in the UK.  How are they going to help?

Comment: @Acccumulation Plugging pipes with papier-maché is not to be recommended. It was different when it was an earth privy at the bottom of the garden. (And no, I'm not that old.)

Comment: TV needs us to be there at the exact time the news are aired; newspapers keep a household informed no matter at what times the persons can read the news. Also, news outlets have political affiliations and with newspapers it's easy to compare sources, with TV no, you need to be there at several specific times and often stations air the news at the same hours. I don't know what the actual motivations were, but it's an oversimplification to say that TV news can replace newspapers, they are different things,  neither can replace the other. Internet doesn't count, too few elderly people can use it.

Comment: @SantiBailors: WRT your last point, I think you must not be acquainted with too many older people (or perhaps the demographics are different where you live).  After all, many of the people who invented the internet, and most other computer tech, are getting up there in years.

Comment: @jamesqf I was thinking of the demographics of Italy (I'm Italian), in my opinion a significant amount of elderly persons don't have internet or the skills to use it. It's true that many do, but even for them it can be more difficult to navigate a website than reading a paper; also when the PC or smartphone has the smallest issue they often need the help of a younger relative or friend otherwise they are stuck. For many elderly persons the Internet is a nice to have but it cannot be the only source available in situations where you must be sure to stay informed, that's why I wouldn't count it.

Comment: I will point out that one can buy a newspaper with e.g. gloves on, leave it untouched for a few days, and then read it and be totally safe.

Comment: Anecdotally, in Belgium the government is still required to publicize and make available law changes via printed medium in order to reach a reasonable expectation of citizens being informed. Citizens are of course allowed to instead use other information sources, and pretty much everyone does. But were the government to cease printing, citizens could legally claim being unaware of a new law. All other sources (TV, internet, radio) sometimes cost money themselves (TV or internet subscription) and always require a device that costs money, and thus citizens cannot be forced to rely on them.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

At least in Italy, this appears to be in part a response to pressure from newspapers and their readers. On March 11th, the director of *la Repubblica* newspaper Carlo Verdelli [published](https://www.repubblica.it/cronaca/2020/03/11/news/coronavirus_ma_non_dimenticatevi_delle_edicole-250946081/) (in Italian) an article asking for newsagents to be included in the list of essential services, saying that "The list is missing a service that is more fundamental 
 now than ever before, that of information". He went on to state that "If [newsagents] were not included in the list, it would cause irreparable damage, not only for newspapers, but most importantly for the citizenry." (my translation)

This is an important point, as a [study undertaken](https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2018/09/27/most-western-europeans-prefer-tv-news-while-use-of-print-outlets-lags/) by the Pew Research Center in 2017 found that while TV and online media dominate, 31% of Italians and 23% of French adults get their news from print media at least daily. This group is likely to be composed of older citizens who will be most affected if they contract the virus, and although this puts them at more risk if they leave their houses to buy a newspaper, it is of higher importance to keep at-risk groups informed.

In addition, another [Pew Research Center study](https://www.pewresearch.org/internet/2011/09/26/part-3-the-role-of-newspapers/) found that newspapers were especially important for coverage of local news that would not otherwise be reported in alternative media - although the study was limited to the US, this is another potential factor that could have influenced the decision.

It seems that France and Italy have decided that informing the populace is especially important in this time of crisis, and that this outweighs the threat public health and the potential spread of disease that the inclusion of newsagents as an essential service poses.

Comment: Thanks! This seems good insight and information, especially that Repubblica article. However, the relevant number here should be the percentage of people that would be left without daily information without newspapers: that is, the percentage of people that read newspapers daily but do not use television, internet or radio daily. Or, even more restrictively, the percentage of people that read newspapers daily and would have no opportunity to switch to any of the other media if newspapers were phased out. I bet those are much lower than 31%.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Agreed, I searched for a study that has looked into this but was unable to find one; would be an interesting statistic. I did find a separate article which studied the importance of print media in covering local news that is unlikely to be picked up by national outlets which could be another factor.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: "the relevant number here should be the percentage of people that would be left without daily information without newspapers". Not that relevant. During a crisis, you want people to get informed in *every possible way*. Not really a good idea to block a medium of communication.

Comment: @Taladris That sounds like a disputable personal view that you are presenting as an axiom. Why is it so important for people to be reachable with more than one kind of media?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: because each media has its advantages and its shortcomings. Also, the French, Italian and Korean situations show that taking measures and having the population following them as soon as possible is critical, so yes, you don't want to miss any opportunity to get people informed. And your claim that "having several means of information is not necessary" is also opinion-based.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Re: "That sounds like a disputable personal view that you are presenting as an axiom": You stated your opinion without qualifying it as such, and Taladris responded with his/her contrary opinion. Your objection to that seems hypocritical to me.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni without getting all critical about your opinions, keep in mind that the extra risk is limited.  If going out of the house was entirely forbidden, except for getting newspapers, then, by all means, it might be worth locking that down as well.  But if a person can already go out for groceries and tobacco (*vino* too, right?) then a newspaper doesn't hurt so why not let it be?  Or, once a day max for food, cigs, paper, vino, together.  Why make the extra fuss for just the newspaper?

Comment: @ruakh Which of the statements I made do you think are disputable and not backed up by facts?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I am not convinced by that argument because the same objection applies to all the other businesses that *were* forbidden instead. If I can already go out to buy groceries, what is the harm in going to buy flowers, new clothes, or visit a car dealer? The additional risk is low. Yet those shops are now closed, and newsagents are open. There must be something special about newspapers, and the existing answers address this.

Comment: *"having several means of information is not necessary" is also opinion-based* But that is precisely what I am asking here. My question, essentially, is "why is having multiple means of information so important that it is worth additional risks of spreading the virus while most other activities are closed?" The other answers address this (and I upvoted two of them and accepted one), but I cannot consider "it is important because I say it is important" a valid argument.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni whoa, that is one serious strawman argument here. you should go into the cow feeding business before you go into bull output mode.  none of your 3 activities serve a compelling purpose w covid, unlike the news rationale we've given you on newspaper.  2 of them require substantial touching of items likely to be touched by others.  and all 3 require you to spend considerable amounts of time in the shop while a paper can be bought in less than 20 seconds with the only substantial risk the cash likely to used.  I can't really say you are  arguing in good faith by this point.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Where is the straw man? I am literally taking one of the arguments you made ("if a person can already go out for groceries and tobacco, then a newspaper doesn't hurt") and pointing out that it is invalid because it would apply equally also to other non-essential activities like buying flowers. "The news rationale" is another argument, and I have nothing against that.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni The impression that you might not be arguing in good faith might come from the fact that you are equating the non-essentiality of buying flowers or visiting a car dealer with the non-essentiality of buying newspapers. Also you have attributed an "it is important because I say it is important" argument to someone but I couldn't see anyone making such an argument. These feel like debating techniques and that often produces the impression of not good faith. Just to be clear, I think your statements are in good faith, but I can see why they might not be coming across as such.

Comment: @SantiBailors Thanks for stepping in as a peacekeeper! This was helpful, now I see the source of our misunderstanding. I am a mathematician; sometimes we have the habit to consider extreme cases to prove points, and I realize that this strategy may be confusing for people with a different formation. The unjustified "it is important because it is important" argument I was pointing out is Taladris' "During a crisis, you want people to get informed in every possible way".

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I'm not sure people would switch as easily as you say. Personally I don't own a radio (except in my car), don't have TV service, and never buy newspapers. If for some reason internet news became unavailable, I wouldn't immediately go out and buy a radio or anything like that. IMO the obvious answer is to start delivering newspapers instead of having everyone go buy one everyday, but maybe that's not a thing in Italy or France.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni if you're a mathematician (and I'm an engineer by training), then please consider what I meant about the difference in exposures and durations thereof under the different types of shopping we addressed.  they're just, *mathematically*, not the same.  that's leaving aside whichever 1 is "essential" or not.  if you want to argue numbers, pick better exposure-equivalents for newspaper purchases.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Sure, I will try. Is the flowers example acceptable for you? I don't buy flowers often, but in my experience it takes the same amount of time, physical contact and interaction as buying a newspaper. Or toys; if I am not mistaken toy shops (for kids) are also closed. I don't think it will be impossible to find a suitable example.

Comment: people will touch and look at flowers, and do so for a while.  toys would also be a long-touch, long-time activity.  my point is not to engage in a discussion about the nitty-gritty details, it is that most shopping activity, including groceries - certainly necessary, is a lot more risky than newspapers.  that's why, when you said, "why not flowers, cars, clothes", I questioned those choices.  but in general, by this point, i think we can agree to disagree.  and i retract my good faith quip for good measure.

Answer (score 17):

Newspapers are the way a lot of people get their information, especially older people.  During a crisis it's especially important that people can access news and government guidance.  And if they're already going out for groceries, the extra risk in picking up a newspaper from a kiosk is fairly limited.  People are also allowed to get cigarettes after all (French version of the quarantines, at least).

Personally?  While I don't mind radio news, I can't stand TV news.  Regardless of the quality or not of the news outlet, I learn a lot less from watching a necessarily superficial 60 second video clip than I do from reading for 60 seconds.

Comment: Italy and France are far from being "less wired-up countries", though. I would imagine that almost everyone there has access to another news outlet such as TV, radio or internet. Among all lifestyle changes imposed by the lockdown, changing news outlet seems like a minor one. (And, for the record, Italians can get cigarettes, too.)

Comment: fair enough.  removed the less-wired.

Answer (score 14):

In many places all over the world, rulers tend to abuse quarantine in order to restrict one freedom or another and/or give their "friends" some business advantage. At least here, in Bulgaria, this is exactly the case.

OTOH, freedom of the press is considered a fundamental and essential tool for protecting other freedoms and rights. That's why administration in more or less democratic societies is reluctant to openly restrict printing and distribution even if common sense dictates otherwise.

Comment: Excellent point. In many industries, bankrupt companies can simply be replaced by newcomers. It might take decades to build a reputable and trustworthy newspaper, though.

Answer (score 2):

On top of all the valid reasons that have already been mentioned, it's important to understand that this level of micromanagement is not the way the French government (at least) is approaching things so far. The government has defined things like information or food as basic needs and allows all businesses in this category to keep operating. For example, there has been no decision to open supermarkets while closing bakeries, cheese shops or fish mongers. And there are anecdotal reports of people making a trip to the pharmacy and buying some cosmetics products just to keep busy.

Furthermore, note that many commentators are criticizing these measures for being too lax, giving too much weight to economic consequences over health concerns and relying too much on calls to the public to limit movements rather than harsh coercive measures. In France, the list of businesses that are currently allowed to stay open include auto parts shops, computer and phone shops, temp agencies, banks and insurance agents, laundry services and of course everything that is not open to the public including construction, manufacturing and deliveries of all kind. There are calls to pause all that but at this point, economic activity is not restricted to absolute necessities.

Conversely, as late as Thursday or Friday, bookstore owners were complaining about lasting damage because online retailers could still operate and were asking for an exception to the restrictions (as is the case in Belgium). I would be surprised if this happens but the minister of the Economy and Finance would not immediately rule it out.

Incidentally, online or even TV news is in a large part based on newspapers stories that are copied and commented all over the place. It might eventually come to that but it's difficult to tell newspapers “you're going to continue to offer contents for free but we will just deprive you on one of your revenue streams and favor your competitors in other media”. Here again, it's legally and politically easier to make the decision at a more general level and at this point, information is deemed important enough. Along the same line, many tobacconists also sell newspapers. It's extremely difficult to imagine closing these shops.

Finally, while the national rules are couched in very general terms, local authorities are allowed to take additional measures. For example, municipalities have closed parks or specific landmarks and at least one mayor specifically banned going out to buy just one baguette or newspaper (you are supposed to make more substantial purchases and stay at home in between).